# Reading hexadecimals from a txt file in C++

Tags: c++, hex

I have a txt file which contains integers in hexadecimal form in each line like:
232B2344
A2BC34893
DEF9433
.....
I would like an elegant way of reading this .txt file in C++ and store them in arrays so that I can make computations on them. Also given the hex 232B2344 say I would like to be in position to say the value of each byte entry

Comment: I have tried to get them line by line but read them as strings...I want my program to realize them as hexadecimals... So I would like to read character by character in each line and store each line in a hex

Comment: Post what you tried and where it goes wrong/want to improve.

Comment: fstream myfile;
myfile.open("entropy.txt");
unsigned int tester;
string test;
myfile >> tester;
cout << hex << tester;

system("pause");

Comment: `std::hex`: When basefield is set to hex, integral numerical values inserted into the stream are expressed in the hexadecimal base (radix 16). - `hex` works ONLY for numerical values and **NOT** for strings.

Answer (score 3):

First include a header

```
#include "sstream"
```

Then get the hexadecimal value in a simple char[] array string using file handling.

char str[100];

Declare an Unsigned int variable...

```
unsigned int value;
```

Then declare a "std::stringstream" variable. e.g.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<<std::hex<<str;
ss>>value;
```

Now the "value" contains the hexadecimal value in file in form of integer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as you describe, each number in the file is a 4 bytes unsigned integer (that fit in 32 bits). Here you have a c++ version for parsing the file and getting the numbers array:

```
std::vector<std::string> fromFileToArray( const std::string & fileName )
{
  std::string line;
  std::vector<uint32_t> numbers;
  std::stringstream ss;
  uint32_t tmp;

  std::ifstream numbersFile( fileName.c_str() );
  while( numbersFile.good() )
  {
    getline( numbersFile, line );
    ss << std::hex << line;
    ss >> tmp;
    numbers.push_back( tmp );
  }
}
```

Comment: `error: aggregate ‘std::stringstream ss’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   std::stringstream ss;` `error: variable ‘std::ifstream numbersFile’ has initializer but incomplete type
     std::ifstream numbersFile( fileName.c_str() );` `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]` with c++14 at https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about this (though it is written with C function, one could help me port this to use C++ functions):

```
const char hexstring[] = "deadbeef10203040b00b1e50", *pos = hexstring;
unsigned char val[12];
size_t count = 0;

/* WARNING: no sanitization or error-checking whatsoever - MAGIC. DO NOT TOUCH. */
for(count = 0; count < sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]); count++) {
    sscanf(pos, "%2hhx", &val[count]);
    pos += 2 * sizeof(char);
}

/* Does it work? */
printf("0x");
for(count = 0; count < sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]); count++)
    printf("%02x", val[count]);
printf("\n");
```

In case of an odd number of hex digits in the string, you have to make sure you prefix it with a starting 0. For example, the string `"f00f5"` will be evaluated as `{0xf0, 0x0f, 0x05}` erroneously by the above example, instead of the proper `{0x0f, 0x00, 0xf5}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... I would like the input to be from a txt file where hexs (like 3929AB3094 no 0x appears in begining) are written LINE by LINE.. Each line corresponds to one hex.. I want to pass these values into hexs into my program...Maybe if I assume that txt entries are strings and then convert them to hexs?

Comment: With [std::ifstream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) you can store line by line in a `char*` and run the `sscanf` loop over it to get your values in byte arrays. No preceeding `0x` is necessary like you can see in the code up there. I am just prepending it to output the value.

Answer (score 0):

To read value in hex format - use `std::hex` from `<iomanip>`. Like in this very short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  int value;
  std::cin >> std::hex >> value;
  std::cout << value;
}
```

Just read as many times as your array has elements.