# How to read hex byte data seperated by spaces in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, hex, byte

I have hexadecimal data values in a file, and I want to store them in an byte array.
I tried to use string streams, but can't manage to make it work.

My data in the file are in the following format

05 02 55 AD FF 0F F0 00 77 01 10 CD 00 BB AA 28
02 34 F1 D0 AD 18 84 3C 5A 21 22 43 78 CA BD FE
...

I tried someting like this

```
std::ifstream inFile("inFile.txt");
std::string line;
uint8_t data[512];

while (std::getline(inFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> data;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: did you looked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562169/reading-hexadecimals-from-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: Here, values are separed by spaces, so the procedure is simpler...

Comment: yea I already had a look at that question. My problem is I can't figure out how to make it take two digits for one byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::hex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) modifier. You can use `std::vector` to simplify data loading:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("inFile.txt");

    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
    data.reserve(512);

    unsigned int temp;
    while(!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> std::hex >> temp;
        data.push_back(temp);
    }

    // Print one element per row
    std::vector<uint8_t>::iterator i;
    for (i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << static_cast<unsigned> (*i) << std::endl;
    }

    // C++11 version (more compact)
    // for (auto i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i) {
    //     std::cout << static_cast<unsigned> (*i) << std::endl;
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the hex numbers are read as `unsigned int`: this is because `int8_t` is treated as `char`, so the extraction from `ifstream` would happens one character at a time, rather than one number at a time. That's only for `temp`, since your result is a `uint8_t` array, as wanted. 
Same happens when printing: I converted back to `unsigned`, so that it is displayed as a number, instead of a character code.

Note that this is an example. You should do some more error checking in your code.

Comment: this does not seem to fix it. The remaining problem is it stores each digit seperatly in my byte array.  0, 5, 0, 2, ....

Comment: Right, I focused on the hex extraction problem. Check the edit.

Comment: this is still storing digits seperately. I guess it takes one char at a time from file. Am not too sure how streams work

Comment: In the question you said " I want to store them in an byte array". What I'm proposing you is actually a bit array, C++ style. Actually, this is a dynamic array, so you don't have to know the number of bytes to store in advance. Maybe you meant something else? Please clarify :)

Comment: I dont really get what you mean by a bit array.  What I try to do, is store each of the value seperated  by a space in my file in different indices of a byte array. In my file, two digits are used to represent the hex value of a byte. In the data I mentioned in my example, the first value is 05. I want to store this in data[0]. I want data[o] == 0x05, data[1] == 0x02, data[2] == 0x55.

Comment: It's exactly what the snippet above does. Added final example.

Comment: what i get is data[0] == 0x00. data[1] == 0x05, data[2] == 0x00, data[3] == 0x02...

Comment: whith your cout, do you get 5? I get 0

Comment: You get `char` number five, which happens to be non-printable. Try now. Works for me.

Comment: well yes It works since you changed temp type from uint8_t to unsigned int. But I don't get why this changes anything

Comment: It's tricky (I corrected it now, after testing): this is because `int8_t` is treated as `char`, so the extraction from `ifstream` happens one character at a time, rather than one number at a time. That's only `temp`, your result is a `uint8_t` array as you want.